# Loading Google map with autocomplete and multiple markers including infowindows

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am newer to google map, i want load map with auto-complete,if i enter particular area on text box map should come up with that area as center,multiple markers with info-windows among that area.

One more thing is if i click on particular info-window i should get div including information about info-window like reviews,

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you....

[Codeigniter Google map library](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers)

You can pass dynamic and multiple addresses with info window.
I have used this and works perfect.